# ViewModel Mvc Display details

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So i have 3 models and need to display information in a view that is on the 3 models, so i created a viewModel that contains the info that i need for the view

model 1:

```
public class Despesa
{
    public int TipoDespesaId { get; set; }

    public int DespesaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição da Despesa")]
    [Required]
    public string DespesaDescricao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Valor")]
    [Required]
    public decimal DespesaValor { get; set; }

    public int TipoPagamentoId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public TipoDespesa TipoDespesa { get; set; }

    public TipoPagamento TipoPagamento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comentário")]
    public string Comentario { get; set; }

}
```

model2:

```
 public class TipoDespesa
{
    public int TipoDespesaId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Despesa")]
    [Required]
    public string TipoDespesaNome { get; set; }
}
```

model3:

```
 public class TipoPagamento
{
    public int TipoPagamentoId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Pagamento")]
    [Required]
    public string TipoPagamentoNome { get; set; }
}
```

myViewModel:

```
 public class ViewModelDetalhes
{
    public string TipoDespesa { get; set; }
    public string TipoPagamento { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public string comentario { get; set; }


}
```

my Details:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        var modelo = db.Despesas.Where(p => p.DespesaId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        if (modelo == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewModelDetalhes model = new ViewModelDetalhes()
        {
            TipoDespesa = modelo.TipoDespesa,
            TipoPagamento = modelo.TipoPagamento,
            Descricao = modelo.DespesaDescricao,
            Valor = modelo.DespesaValor,
            comentario = modelo.Comentario,

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

I dont know how i can get the values of TipoPagamento and TipoDespesa here should i do a include on the modelo? im a bit confused and need to know how to retrieve the values TipoPagamento and TipoDespesa associated with the main class Despesas.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ViewModel

```
public class ViewModelDetalhes
{
    public string TipoDespesa{ get; set; }
    public string TipoPagamento { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public string comentario { get; set; }


}
```

If you want to lazy load make use of Virtual

```
public class Despesa
{
    public int TipoDespesaId { get; set; }

    public int DespesaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição da Despesa")]
    [Required]
    public string DespesaDescricao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Valor")]
    [Required]
    public decimal DespesaValor { get; set; }

    public int TipoPagamentoId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public virtual TipoDespesa TipoDespesa { get; set; }

    public virtual TipoPagamento TipoPagamento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comentário")]
    public string Comentario { get; set; }

}
```

You Detail ActionResult

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        var modelo = db.Despesas.Where(p => p.DespesaId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        if (modelo == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewModelDetalhes model = new ViewModelDetalhes()
        {
            TipoDespesa = modelo.TipoDespesa.TipoDespesaNome ,
            TipoPagamento = modelo.TipoPagamento.TipoPagamentoNome,
            Descricao = modelo.DespesaDescricao,
            Valor = modelo.DespesaValor,
            comentario = modelo.Comentario,

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

If you do not want to eager load use include. No need to add virtual to your POCO.

In your Detail ActionResult

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            var modelo = db.Despesas.Include("TipoDespesa").Include("TipoPagamento").Where(p => p.DespesaId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            if (modelo == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewModelDetalhes model = new ViewModelDetalhes()
            {
                TipoDespesa = modelo.TipoDespesa.TipoDespesaNome ,
                TipoPagamento = modelo.TipoPagamento.TipoPagamentoNome,
                Descricao = modelo.DespesaDescricao,
                Valor = modelo.DespesaValor,
                comentario = modelo.Comentario,

            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

Read More Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Some questions, that virtual in this case is for what??, i understanded how can i do the same without the includes, i thought if i created the modelview i didnt need to use includes :S

Comment: The include worked, but why use the viewModel if we can do everything with the includes :S

Comment: Include keyword tells the EF to load your related entities. If you had used Virtual for that property you didn't need to use Include in your Linq query. ViewModel in other hand is just a class that specifies what you want to display in the View. In your case you don't need a viewModel you could have just used your Despesas Model. But by using a viewModel you have only selected the properties you like to display in the view. It's good that you dont have extra properties in terms of bandwidth, security, processing, etc... As a good practice i always use viewModel

Comment: ViewModel is not a replacement for Include. They are totally different things.

Comment: Soo basicly ViewModel is good to make the code more cleaner right?, cause in my case as you said i dont need a viewModel i could just include the classes i need and use the atirbutes, is the use of virtual a good practice??

Comment: Yes viewModel is always a better solution. When view's becomes complex you will see the real benefit of viewModels. Personally i dislike the use of virtual keyword in my Model. When using virtual ,EF will load all the related data's even when I don't need them. By making the use of include, I can load those entities whenever I want them. Imagine what happens when you have 10000 related entities for a single class and you have used virtual. Every time you query that class it is loading those entities. Hence, I always stick to Include's (i.e. Eager Loading) it's just a better practice really

Comment: Thank you fantastic explanation, sorry for my bad english :)